# reference to gazebo in documents

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Dear my friends,
Hello,
I did my project, and now I'm writing my documents, so, please let me know how can i reference to Gazebo, i should reference just to website or there is any article or any other things?!
i just this [survey](http://ranger.uta.edu/%7Egianluca/papers/StMa_PETRA11.pdf).
also i find this [article](http://robotics.usc.edu/publications/media/uploads/pubs/394.pdf)
Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/4079/reference-to-gazebo-in-documents/) by [Vahid](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/342/vahid/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 91 on 2013-08-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Check out this question:

http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/3240/reference-paper-for-gazebo/

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-08-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0